# Deleting all the nested child nodes in a deep nested 1D array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a 1D deep nested array:

```
nestedObj: [
   { id: 1, parentId: null, taskCode: '12', taskName: 'Parent one', duration: 0, assignee: '', crewCount: 0, startDate: null, endDate: null, dependencies: []},
   { id: 2, parentId: 1, taskCode: '12100', taskName: 'Child one', duration: 0, assignee: '', crewCount: 0, startDate: null, endDate: null, dependencies: []},
   { id: 3, parentId: 2, taskCode: '12200', taskName: 'SubChild one', duration: 0, assignee: '', crewCount: 0, startDate: null, endDate: null, dependencies: []},
   { id: 4, parentId: 3, taskCode: '122001', taskName: 'Sub-dub-Child one', duration: 0, assignee: '', crewCount: 0, startDate: null, endDate: null, dependencies: []},
   { id: 5, parentId: null, taskCode: '13', taskName: 'Parent two', duration: 0, assignee: '', crewCount: 0, startDate: null, endDate: null, dependencies: []}
]
```

As in the above data structure, the tree view with taskName is stated below

```
-> Parent one
        -> Child one
                   -> SubChild one
                                  ->Sub-sub-Child one
-> Parent two
```

here if I delete a node(say Parent one) then all its nested children(till the Sub-sub-Child one) should get deleted. So how can I possibly do this using recursion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64750319/4645334 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64785033/prepare-a-list-by-depth#comment114545914_64785033

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const nestedObj = [
   { id: 1, parentId: null, taskCode: '12', taskName: 'Parent one', duration: 0, assignee: '', crewCount: 0, startDate: null, endDate: null, dependencies: []},
   { id: 2, parentId: 1, taskCode: '12100', taskName: 'Child one', duration: 0, assignee: '', crewCount: 0, startDate: null, endDate: null, dependencies: []},
   { id: 3, parentId: 2, taskCode: '12200', taskName: 'SubChild one', duration: 0, assignee: '', crewCount: 0, startDate: null, endDate: null, dependencies: []},
   { id: 4, parentId: 3, taskCode: '122001', taskName: 'Sub-dub-Child one', duration: 0, assignee: '', crewCount: 0, startDate: null, endDate: null, dependencies: []},
   { id: 5, parentId: null, taskCode: '13', taskName: 'Parent two', duration: 0, assignee: '', crewCount: 0, startDate: null, endDate: null, dependencies: []}
];
function deepDelete(id) {
  const index = nestedObj.findIndex((element) => element.id === id);
  if (index === -1) return;
  
  nestedObj.splice(index, 1);
  
  const childElements = nestedObj.filter((element) => element.parentId === id);
  for (const element of childElements) {
    deepDelete(element.id);
  }
}

deepDelete(2);
console.log(nestedObj);
```